# How to Connect AWS LightSail Database to Laravel system?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, plesk, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to connect aws LightSail database to Laravel system hosted in Plesk.

.env file

DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=52.113.101.69
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=new1
DB_USERNAME=awsUser
DB_PASSWORD=123456789

[image]

1. How to connect Lightsail Database to Laravel?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the same DB using shared credentials?

Comment: @svikramjeet DB working on LightSail but can't connect to system

Comment: Have you configured the public availability of your MySQL database in Amazon Lightsail? By default, Your managed database in Amazon Lightsail is accessible only by your Lightsail resources (instances, load balancers, etc.) that are in the same Lightsail account.